# Not able to calculate a formula in EPPlus From Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, epplus

I have excel with a number of calculation references, need to calculate the output from excel in the excel multiple references with a different sheet, whenever I'll passed a new value it'll give #Value after the calculation method call.

```
  using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[2];
            object val = worksheet.Cells["B1621"].Value;
            worksheet.Cells["B1621"].Value = 500;
            package.Workbook.Calculate(calculateOptions);
            package.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;
            var cellValue = worksheet.Cells["H1605"].Value;
        }
```

Comment: Not all functions/formulas are supported. You can try to identify which formulas are giving the parser trouble by logging what the formula parser is doing as described here: https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/Formula-Calculation/54db0238689fe2ae34440da9d1a9a6b7bdb08a52#trouble-shootinglogging

Comment: There is no error, I have checked already, also max 255 characters allowed in cell error receiving while saving excel file @T.Schwarz